# What is the solution for "Error message "could not connect to server in Spring Initilizr?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-initializr

https://github.com/spring-io/start.spring.io/issues/990

> When configuring a project I encountered a weird error. I don't know
> the suggested way of naming project but since it isn't the artifact
> name I though of naming it more 'commercially' using proper diacritics
> of my language. Pressing 'Generate' resulted in an 'Could not connect
> to server. Please check your network.' error.

Comment: Pointing to an offside link, isn't asking a question. Please readhttps://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question.

Comment: The issue on GitHub indicates that this is an open bug in Spring Initializr. What do you expect by asking this question here? Either wait until the developers of Spring Initializr have fixed the bug, or use a different name without diacritics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you want to create a spring boot project in spring initializer you must be connected with internet maybe your internet connection was`nt available that time.
connect with internet then try to create project and try to add all important depedencies that you need for example spring web etc..